# How to install Patch SUPEE 8788 V2

Tags: patches

I have got Magento version 1.9.2.0 I would like to install the new security patch 8788 v2. I have not installed the 8788v1 yet.
I know the installation process states, Revert SUPEE-8788 if you have already installed it, Revert SUPEE-1533 if you have already installed it, Deploy SUPEE-3941 if it hasn’t already been installed.
My issue is I can not find out if SUPEE-1533 and SUPEE-3941 is installed because it is not in my app-etc-applied.patches.list and when I check on www.magereport.com, it does not indicate these patches.
I need advise on how to install this new patch successfully please.

Comment: have you tried to install 8788, what errors you have??

Comment: I not try to install 8788 yet. I just need to find out if 3941 is installed on it or I have to install it after installing 8788.

Comment: I have just Revert SUPEE-1533 as indicated and tried to installed SUPEE-3941 but unabled to install because patch already installed.

Comment: I tried to patch 8788 v2 but I get HUNK errors